# Removing entity violates not null constraint on field

Tags: postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I have this entity

```
@Entity
class PieceAvailable {

    ...

    @JoinColumn(name = "id_product", referencedColumnName = "id_product")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Product idProduct;

    ...

}
```

I also have Product entity however it's code is pretty much irrelevant (there are no relation from Product back to PieceAvailable).

And there is also a code

```
PieceAvailable pa = entityManager.find(PieceAvailable.class, 52);
entityManager.remove(pa);
```

persistence.xml (testPU persistence-unit is probably not used right now)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="crm-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/crm</jta-data-source>
    <class>my.company.crm.server.entity.CrmSetting</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>

    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  <persistence-unit name="testPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>my.company.crm.server.entity.CrmSetting</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

which throws exception:

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception
>   [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR:  null value in
>   column "id_product" violates not-null constraint   Detail: Failing row
>   contains (null)(52, null, 2015-08-12 16:05:41.166, 1,
>   205.33000000000001, null, null, null, null, null, 2015-08-12 16:05:41.166, 0, null). Error Code: 0 Call: **UPDATE piece_available SET
>   id_invoice_position_pz = ?, id_piece_available_original = ?,
>   id_product = ?, id_store = ? WHERE (id_piece_available = ?)**     bind =>
>   [5 parameters bound]

My goal is to remove entity as clearly stated. I don't know why eclipselink firstly fill relations with null. But it's happening. This violates not null constraint which obviously is setted up in my PostgreSQL. In JPA also is clearly stated that for this mapping optional = false. So it's required.

How can I avoid this exception? I wouldn't like to delete this not null constraint.

Comment: Could you post some additional code and configuration? I have not tried this against PostgreSQL but I tried the same scenario and this works for me, delete statement is generated after inserts, no update performed.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What would be useful? I can try to prepare minimal project but this will be much effort

Comment: This is actually exactly what I did myself, I created a simple maven project importing just EclipseLink, junit and hsqldb, created two simple entities and a test method. If you could share something like that it would be ideal. Alternatively you could start by sharing your persistence.xml and the exact code performing the removal in your case.

Comment: Please show us the `create table` statements (including all constraint definitions) for the tables in question. But the error is pretty clear I think. The column `piece_available.id_product` was created using `NOT NULL`. If you do want to allow null values in there, you need to remove that constraint from your `create table` statement.

Comment: I added persistence.xml to my post. About the code... these 2 lines with entityManager are exactly those which throws exception. If you would like to know any other thing please let me know. In meantime I try to create minimal project.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, of course I have constraint on id_product, the problem is that I don't want to have nulls in id_product. I want remove PieceAvailable entity and EclipseLink in this entityManager.remove method seems to update this entity with nulls... BEFORE it call DELETE statement to database. My question is why this UPDATE is proccessed in first place and how to avoid it.

Comment: The joys of an **O**bfuscated**R**elational**M**odel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was preparing minimal example project for this topic I found out that my PieceAvailable entity is pretty uncommon.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "piece_available")
public class PieceAvailable implements Serializable {

    ...

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_piece_available")
    private Integer idPieceAvailable;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id_product", referencedColumnName = "id_product")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Product idProduct;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id_piece_available_original", referencedColumnName = "id_piece_available")
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    private PieceAvailable idPieceAvailableOriginal;

    ...
}
```

PieceAvailable entity maps relation to itself (field idPieceAvailableOriginal) and in some cases in my application it seems that entity maps to itself. In these cases UPDATE statement will occur before removal. So when I persist entity like:

```
PieceAvailable pa = new PieceAvailable();
...
pa.setIdPieceAvailableOriginal(pa);
```

Then after invocation remove method with entity like this above as argument I will get my exception.

I will have to fix this strange relation. However for now I found that as workaround I can set null in idPieceAvailableOriginal before removal and I won't get any exception.

```
PieceAvailable pa = entityManager.find(PieceAvailable.class, 52);
pa.setIdPieceAvailableOriginal(null);
entityManager.remove(pa);
```